# Spring Security не авторизовывает

Tags: java, jsp, spring-security

Имеется некоторый проект на котором Spring Security получает форму логина (вообще вся рега скомуниздена [от сюда](https://hellokoding.com/registration-and-login-example-with-spring-xml-configuration-maven-jsp-and-mysql/) )
До какого то момента все прекрасно себя отрабатывало. Сейчас непонятно почему при логине на 100% имеющийся в базе аккаунт выскакивает error о том что данные не валинды. Форма с JSP отправляется на POST метод "login" для Spring Security , от туда спринг включает кастомный гет метод логина куда вкладывает строку "error" которая к прибольшому сожалению в случае ошибок лишь пустую строку (но не null) отображение в консоли которой не дало никакого толку.

login jsp:

```
<form method="POST" action="${contextPath}/login" class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-heading">
            <spring:message code="log.in" />
        </h2>

        <div class="form-group ${error != null ? 'has-error' : ''}">
            <span>${message}</span> <input name="username" type="text"
                class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus="true" /> <input
                name="password" type="password" class="form-control"
                placeholder="Password" /> <span>${error}</span> <input
                type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
            <input id="remember_me" name="_spring_security_remember_me"
                type="checkbox" /> <label for="remember_me" class="inline"><spring:message
                    code="remember.me" /></label>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
                <spring:message code="log.in" />
            </button>
            <h4 class="text-center">
                <a href="${contextPath}/registration"><spring:message
                        code="create.an.account" /></a>
            </h4>
            <h4 class="text-center">
                <a href="${contextPath}/forgotPassword"><spring:message
                        code="forgot.password" /></a>
            </h4>
        </div>

</form>
```

UserController , GET method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
    System.out.println(error);
    if (error != null)
        model.addAttribute("error", "Your username and password is invalid.");

    if (logout != null)
        model.addAttribute("message", "You have been logged out successfully.");

    return "login";
}
```

Собственно кода там еще много можно было бы приложить и если у кого какие догадки есть то говорите что надо добавить. Ну и ссылка на гит проект:
https://github.com/6ruceWayne/Testowiki

Comment: Вы хронически не принимаете ответы, это снижает желание вам помогать.

Comment: Привычку "лайкать" ответ обещаю выработать :) Предыдущие темы исправил :) просто не думал что это важно , вот

Comment: В дополнение:
Залил старую версию проекта где регистрация 100% работала
Не заработало.
Соответственно вся проблема у меня локально. Попробовал пересоздать сервер Томката. Не помогло. В Оксигене при нажатии ПКМ по проекту есть пункт Спринг утилиты и него подпункт очистки кеша. Не помогло. Удалял репозиторий. Не помогло. Что еще можно попробовать?